# Perform calculations with fields of database in NSPredicate Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I creating a method for recovering product from my database, each item has the fields height, width and percErro (percentage error),

The user enters the width and height you want to search, eg: 15 x 15cm

Then the method should bring compatible products with these numbers, taking into account the percentage of error allowed in its registration.

Let's say the product is the database is 14 x 14cm and the error percentage is 10% (1.4cm), then you search for a product that is 15 x 15cm

In my query I have to do something like this:

```
[query appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "(heigthInserted * percErro / 1000) <= (height * percErro / 100)"

[query appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "AND (widthInserted * percErro / 1000) <= (width * percErro / 100)"

 NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: query];
    [Request setPredicate: predicate];
```

This should bring me all the products that the percentage of error does not exceed 10% (1.4 cm)

I know NSPredicate does not accept mathematical operations, how could I get the result calculating this percentage of error?

**

> Solved

**

> I accepted the answer of pbasdf and conclude that mathematical
>   operators work in NSPredicate, but must be written according to the
>   documentation of this link: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:)
>
> Below my 100% functional method with operators:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)findWithDimensoes:(NSMutableArray*)formatos :(float)largura :(float)altura{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:TABLE_NAME inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"altura" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"largura" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *arraySD = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1,sortDescriptor2,nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:arraySD];
    [request setFetchLimit:20];

    NSMutableString *query = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    [query appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" (habilitado == true) "]];

    if (formatos != nil) {
        for (ProdutoDimensao *d in formatos) {
            if ([d.id intValue] > 0) {
               if (([formatos indexOfObject:d] < formatos.count)) {
                    [query appendString:@" AND "];
                }

                [query appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" (produtoDimensao.id == %d) ",[d.id intValue]]];
            }
        }
    }

    [query appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" AND altura >=  from:subtract:(%lf,multiply:by:(%lf,percErro)) AND altura <= add:to:(%lf,multiply:by:(%lf,percErro)) ",altura,altura,altura,altura]];
[query appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" AND largura >=  from:subtract:(%lf,multiply:by:(%lf,percErro)) AND largura <= add:to:(%lf,multiply:by:(%lf,percErro)) ",largura,largura,largura,largura]];


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:query];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


    return [results mutableCopy];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't understand your format strings (`percErro` could be factored out from both sides of the comparison, for example).  But your final statement is wrong: it *is* possible to use (basic) mathematical calculations in predicates.  The correct syntax is in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:) for `NSExpression`.  In your case you will need something like this:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"divide:by:(multiply:by:(height,percErro),100) <= %@ AND divide:by:(multiply:by:(width,percErro),100) <= %@",heightInserted, widthInserted];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried to use the NSExpression operators the way mentioned, however it seems that did not work, will they work if direct added in [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @ "..."]; the way I did?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show what you've tried, and what error/results you got?  Thanks.

Comment: @jucajl Thanks.  I think the "formula" you are using might be wrong (it's equivalent to "searchHeight >= height AND (searchHeight * percErro) <= (height * percErro)", which will only be true if searchHeight == height.  Can you explain what criteria you want to match against?

Comment: Imagine that the user enters the height values: 8.0 width: 15, assume that the percErro of all products is 0.05 then the query would look like this "8.0 >= databaseHeight AND (8.0 * 0.05) <= (databaseheight * 0.05)," I have a product which has 8.5 x 18.0, then it should be returned by the search, but it does not.

Comment: @jucajl Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but I still don't understand your search criteria.  With your example values, the first clause ("8.0 >= 8.5") is false.  But I think we might need too many comments: would you like to discuss it in chat?

Comment: So even entering the value 8.6, no record is found, we can talk on the chat, I never used it, so I do not know how to call you, I'm waiting for you to contact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105832/discussion-between-pbasdf-and-jucajl).

Comment: I solved the case and was skinning the problem with an incorrect logic, updated the question and added the solution, then conclude that mathematical operators work in NSPredicate, but must be written according to the documentation of this link:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:

Comment: @jucajl Thanks - glad you got the logic sorted.